# Check if any word from a string is in an array (Case insensitive)

Tags: php

I hope this is not a duplicate, but I couldn't find something matching.

I'm getting the following response from an api:

```
Ingredients: Whey, Beef, Egg, Nuts
```

I'm using this as a string in my script, and now I want to check, if any of the words in the string match with my array.
What I'm using right now is:

```php
$i = count(array_intersect($array, explode(" ", preg_replace("/[^A-Za-z0-9' -]/", "", $string))));
              if ($i >= 1){
                echo "True";
              }
              else {
                echo "False";
              }
```

This works fine, but if the response is not `Whey, Beef, Egg, Nuts` but instead `whey, beef, EGG, nuts` this doesn't work anymore.

I then used this:

```php
array_search(strtolower($string), array_map('strtolower', $array));
```

but this only works with one ingredient.

I would appreciate any help!

Comment: Have the words in your array be lowercase to begin with (or convert them to that once), and then pass `strtolower($string)` to your nested preg_replace/explode call ...?

Comment: I think what you need is a ```foreach``` loop. Maybe this helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9464559/how-to-check-if-string-is-in-array-with-php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use *array_**u**intersect,* which takes a comparison function in which you can do case-insensitive comparison with *strcasecmp:*

```
$response = 'Ingredients: Whey, bEEf, EgG, NuTs';

$items = array_map('trim', array_slice(preg_split('/[:,]/', $response), 1));

$array = [ 'Beef', 'Nuts'];

$result = array_uintersect($array, $items, fn($a, $b) => strcasecmp($a, $b));

print_r($result);
```

Comment: This is a nice solution, the problem I have is that the `$response` sometimes starts with "Ingredients:" and sometimes with something completely different.

Comment: But that is a separate thing: how to create an array from the response.

Comment: Thank you very much, this helped. 
I'm now just checking if the array() produced by `$result` is empty or not.

Comment: Note that the regex pattern is a bit "cheap". $items will only be correct if there is only one colon in the string and it is before the first comma. If not you would need to adjust the regex pattern.